# Facing issue while implementing € in "vue-d3-charts"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, frontend, vue-component

We are facing issue while implementing "€" symbol for currency, for "$" it works fine. Code snippet:
Working fine with below code:

```
import { D3BarChart } from 'vue-d3-charts';

export default {
    name: "D3Chart",
    components: {
        D3BarChart,
    },
    props: {
      aemdata: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      },
      billingdata: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      },
    },
     data() {

    return {
      topUpColor : '#D3D3D3',
      deductionColor : '#696969',
      
      chart_config: {
        key: 'monthYear',
        values: ['topUp', 'deduction'],
        axis: { 
          yTicks: 10,
          yFormat: '$',
        },
        color: {
          keys: {
            'topUp': '#D3D3D3',
            'deduction': '#696969',
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
}
```

Working screenshot:
[image]

But when we are using below code:

```
import { D3BarChart } from 'vue-d3-charts';

export default {
    name: "D3Chart",
    components: {
        D3BarChart,
    },
    props: {
      aemdata: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      },
      billingdata: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      },
    },
     data() {

    return {
      topUpColor : '#D3D3D3',
      deductionColor : '#696969',
      
      chart_config: {
        key: 'monthYear',
        values: ['topUp', 'deduction'],
        axis: { 
          yTicks: 10,
          yFormat: '€',
        },
        color: {
          keys: {
            'topUp': '#D3D3D3',
            'deduction': '#696969',
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
}
```

It is throwing Below error

> "An error occurred while showing the error page Unfortunately an error
> occurred and while showing the error page another error occurred
>
> Error details: TypeError: this.chart.destroyChart is not a function
>
> Go back to home"

Comment: so, to be clear, the ONLY difference is `yFormat: '€'` instead of `yFormat: '$'`? (and you don't actually have the `**`, of course)

Comment: yes, for highlighting that i have put **

Comment: highlighting doesn't work in code :p what if you use a different character, like "x" ... just to test

Comment: all are throwing error

Comment: And in code i am not highlighting, in this post only to highlight that line i have put that :)

Comment: so, only `'$'` works? that is odd - I guess `yFormat` expects only certain values

Comment: yes, seems but ideally it should support other currency as well.

Comment: The issue here is not the currency symbol. That `"$"` string is passed to d3-format, in which $ will *"apply currency symbols per the locale definition"*. If you want a different currency symbol, change your locale: https://github.com/d3/d3-format. But I bet this 'vue-d3-charts' doesn't allow that.

Comment: Yes, i already tried to change locale and vue-d3-charts not allowing.